# Wii Fit Plus: any way to choose which pet belongs to which person?

Tags: wii-fit-plus

In Wii Fit Plus I have two Miis and two pets. For some reason it binds the "wrong" pet to the "wrong" Mii. Essentially I'm playing with my girlfriend's dog, and she's playing with mine.
Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: The only thing I've found that works so far is breaking up with the girlfriend (had the same problem with her dog/my cat). That might be an extreme way to go, though.

Comment: Haha, I love both my girlfriend and her dog a lot more than the Wii Fit Plus, so that's pretty much out of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing the game for a few weeks, I am under the strong impression that **it is not possible**.